# How to enable publish button automatically after changing both the fields

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to generate the auto publish button when a user changes the date fields and selects an option. I am stuck. I don't know what's wrong. Here is my code.

```
<select>
  <option value="Section A">Section A</option>
  <option value="Section B">Section B</option>
  <option value="Section C">Section C</option>
</select>

<input class="time" id="date_one" type="text" />
<input class="time" id="date_two" type="text" />
<input class="time" id="date_two" type="text" />

<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="pub" value="Publish"/>
```

The three input fields are date picker. A button only enables when all these three input fields and select field is changed. My jquery code would be:

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
   validatePub();
});

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){
   validatePub();
});

function validatePub() {
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() != "" )
    {
        if(($(".time").val().length !=" "))
        {

            $("#pub").removeAttr("disabled"); 
        }
        else {
            $("#pub").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this works.

```js
            $('select').on('change',function(){
               validatePub();
            });

            $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){
               validatePub();
            });

            function validatePub() {
              var resultFalse = '';
                $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
                  if ($(this).val() == "") {
                    resultFalse += false;
                  }
                })
                if (resultFalse == '') {
                  $("#pub").removeAttr("disabled"); 
                } else {
                  $("#pub").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
             }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="Section A">Section A</option>
  <option value="Section B">Section B</option>
  <option value="Section C">Section C</option>
</select>

<input class="time" id="date_one" type="text" />
<input class="time" id="date_two" type="text" />
<input class="time" id="date_two" type="text" />

<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="pub" value="Publish"/>
```

Comment: The answer helps. But it only works if select option is changed after the input fields. If I am changing select field before inputs, not working, You are absolutely apt at your point but maybe it's because the input carries a datepicker and this might be troubling me.

Comment: Eh... what? What does the select-button have to do with anything? The example I provided shows that it works regardless of what you change, when. So I don't really understand what you want. Currently, as long as all input-fields have content, the submit-button has the disabled removed. If there is one empty input, the disabled stays. What is missing?